# SQL correct way of joining if the other parameter is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code and its temporary tables so you can run it.

```
create table #student
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    firstname varchar(50),
    lastname varchar(50)
)

create table #quiz
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    quiz_name varchar(50)
)

create table #quiz_details
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    quiz_id int,
    student_id int
)

insert into #student(firstname, lastname)
values ('LeBron', 'James'), ('Stephen', 'Curry')

insert into #quiz(quiz_name)
values('NBA 50 Greatest Player Quiz'), ('NBA Top 10 3 point shooters')

insert into #quiz_details(quiz_id, student_id)
values (1, 2), (2, 1)


drop table #student
drop table #quiz
drop table #quiz_details
```

So as you can see lebron james takes the quiz nba top 10 3 point shooters quiz and stephen curry takes the nba 50 greatest player quiz.

All I want is to get the thing that they didn't take yet for example LeBron hasn't taken the 50 greatest player quiz so what I want is like this.

```
id   quiz_name                    firstname  lastname
----------------------------------------------------
1    NBA 50 Greatest Player Quiz  NULL       NULL
```

I want 2 parameters, the id of lebron and the id of the quiz so that I will know that lebron or stephen hasn't taken it yet, but how would I do that if the value of the `student_id` is still null?

My attempt:

```
select
    QD.id,
    Q.quiz_name,
    S.firstname,
    S.lastname
from 
    #quiz_details QD
inner join 
    #quiz Q on Q.id = QD.quiz_id
inner join 
    #student S on S.id = QD.student_id
```

Comment: What a great job posting data like this!!! I wish everyone did that. I am pretty sure I know what you want for output. I will write up a query in a sec.

Comment: Agreed, for a first post, this is very well written, and exactly how people providing answers to T-SQL questions like them. With DDL, **Consumable** sample data, and an expected result set. Well done SCrub. :)

Comment: @Larnu All Hail all the Scrubs! hahaha :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
-- filter out the student and quiz you want
DECLARE @qid INT = 1
DECLARE @sid INT = 1

SELECT * 
FROM #student AS s
INNER JOIN #quiz AS q  -- you want the quiz
 ON 1=1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #quiz_details AS qd  -- left join here to get result where rows not found
 ON qd.id = q.id 
 AND qd.student_id=s.id
WHERE s.id = @sid
 AND q.id = @qid
 AND qd.id IS NULL -- only return quizes not taken
```

Comment: this kinda works for me! this is more complicated, but the first one was a big help already, thanks sir! i hope i could up vote but i still have small rep

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Nice answer; only thing I would recommend is using `cross join` rather than an `inner join` with no join condition. Though they're equivalent, I believe it's  clearer to use a `cross join` explicitly, as an `inner join` without a condition isn't really an inner join. It also lets you get rid of the `1=1` fluff

Comment: ...although there's a condition on `#quiz` in the `WHERE` clause, which should be moved up to that join (which would preclude using `CROSS JOIN` there)

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure you want something along these lines. This will give you the quiz values and return NULL for the student and quiz_details when there is no matching data.

```
select *
from #quiz q
left join #quiz_details qd on q.id = qd.quiz_id
left join #student s on s.id = qd.student_id
```

Comment: I actually wrote the same query, but it doesn't give a NULL value for the first and last name.  Maybe the OP doesn't care about that, but his original example shows a NULL value for those fields.

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand what the OP is looking for as output.

Comment: Yes, I'm a bit confused as well. Even though the OP seems happy with the results I still want to try to get the NULL first and last name fields as requested--at least just for fun.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
Select Q.id , Q.quiz_name ,S.firstname, S.lastname
from 
    #quiz Q                -- cross join, returns N*K results, do not use without 
    CROSS JOIN #student S  -- where condition that limits it - SAS solution is nicer!
where not exists (select 1 from #quiz_details where quiz_id = Q.id and student_id = S.id)
```

will give you

```
id  quiz_name                         firstname     lastname
1   NBA 50 Greatest Player Quiz       LeBron        James
2   NBA Top 10 3 point shooters       Stephen       Curry
```

---

Edit: changed code to explicit `cross join` rather then implicit, leaving both in here for comparison

```
SELECT #quiz Q, # student S           -- old implicit syntax - comma is easily missed
```

vs.

```
SELECT #quiz Q CROSS JOIN #student S  -- makes it clearer what is wanted
```

Comment: That actually is a join. It is the antiquated way of doing a cross join.

Comment: What I am saying is that #quiz Q, #student S is a join. It is a cross join. I didn't say your solution was incorrect. I was trying to point out that what you have is a cross join with out of date syntax. I much prefer explicit join syntax. :)

Comment: ah, now I think I got it. So yes, it is a cross join thats limited by the where. will adapt my comment in code

Comment: Or even better, change your code to use an explicit cross join. But you definitely got the point of what I was fumbling to say.

Answer (score 2):

My take on it - similar to Patrick's answer with a cross join.

Full sample available at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f63a/16)

```
select
  Q.Quiz_Name Quiz
 ,S.LastName Last
 ,S.FirstName First
 ,QD.Quiz_ID
 ,QD.Student_ID
from 
/* Get a full list of ALL Test/Student combinations */
           quiz Q 
CROSS JOIN student S 
/* Join the taken tests to the combinations */
 LEFT JOIN quiz_details QD on Q.id = QD.quiz_id
                          and S.id = QD.student_id
/* Only select where no Quiz_ID exists */
WHERE QD.Quiz_ID IS NULL
ORDER BY Q.Quiz_Name, S.Lastname, S.FirstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.firstname, s.lastname, q.id as not_taken_quiz_id, q.quiz_name as not_taken_quiz_name
from #student s
left join #quiz_details qd on s.id = qd.student_id
left join #quiz q on q.id <> qd.quiz_id
```

This will give you each student along with the quiz that they have not taken.