# SQL Server - Trying to join 2 foreign keys from 1 primary key in a procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-keys, primary-key

Trying to join 2 foreign keys from 1 primary key in a procedure: Its very hard for me, and I want to make a code that will be simple. sitting for hours of hours from evening until morning and didn't find any answer to this issue. very hard. In mySQL there is an answer on this site but it doesn't work.

I must insert the each primary key (there are 2 in two different tables) to different tables. I tried with the "view" option but it didn't work.

My procedure is to write a story and insert an image, each one of them has ID.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UserStory
    @UserID [INT],
    @story [NVARCHAR] (120),
    @img [VARCHAR](MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Stories (StoryText) 
    VALUES (@story)

    INSERT INTO dbo.Images (img) 
    VALUES (@img)

    SELECT 
        imagesInStories.imgID3, imagesInStories.StoryID3, 
        Stories.imgID2, Users_Stories.ID2, Users_Stories.StoryID2
    FROM   
        Images B3, Stories T1, Table_Users
    INNER JOIN 
        imagesInStories G1 ON B3.imgID3 = G1.imgID
    INNER jOIN 
        imagesInStories G2 ON B3.imgID2 =  G2.imgI
END
```

Why does this code cause errors? [image: error1][erorr...could not be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWjQz.png) (I'll use Stories T1 and Table_Users later) right now the error just ruin it all...lol

My mission here is to insert the primary to two foreign key from two different tables (could be more if so..) .

The tables I use:

```
[dbo].[Images] , [Table_Users],  [dbo].[Stories], [Users_Stories],
```

`[imagesInStories]` each has those IDs.

If any complain,  tell me and I'll fix the writing and question.

**P.S**

I changed each key to have it's own unique name as ID2 and ID3 not same as

```
Images.ID, Stories.ID and/or imagesInStories.imgID, Stories.imgID
```

Is it necessary?

Thanks
E.

Comment: could you use `temp` tables? I think it is much understandable in that way. try to refer on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190016/sql-correct-way-of-joining-if-the-other-parameter-is-null to make your own `temp` tables

Comment: it is unclear what is your problem here. You mention error but didn't include any error messages. Please post your schema, sample data and expected result

Comment: Very unclear as to why you are inserting into the two tables, and then querying another that doesnt seem to have any inserts. Could you also stick to the one sort of joins? At the moment you are doing a cross join across B3, T1 and Table_Users. Is that what you intended?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should **most definitely** not **mix** these two styles! Pick the new, proper ANSI JOIN syntax for **all** your joins - **right now!**

Comment: @marc_s What is ANSI JOIN ?

Comment: @Squirrel Hi i put the error screen shot. thanks

Comment: @Doywaser: **research it!** It's using `INNER JOIN`,   `LEFT OUTER JOIN` etc. instead of just listing a comma-separated list of tables in the `FROM` clause. It's the way **things should be done** when joining tables

Comment: @Squirrel I put the error screenshots. I want to use the same table with primary key twice!, each time to pass the primary key to the other table with the same foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

if you have assign alias to a table, you must use that and can't use the table name anymore

```
    SELECT 
        imagesInStories.imgID3, imagesInStories.StoryID3, 
        Stories.imgID2, Users_Stories.ID2, Users_Stories.StoryID2
    FROM   
        Images B3, Stories T1, Table_Users
    INNER JOIN 
        imagesInStories G1 ON B3.imgID3 = G1.imgID
    INNER jOIN 
        imagesInStories G2 ON B3.imgID2 =  G2.imgI
```

so in the above query `imagesInStories.imgID3` should be either `G1.imgID3` or `G2.imgID3`

and the other column also.

Note : please avoid the comma notation in `FROM` and use proper ANSI `JOIN` style

Comment: @Sguirrel Hi, I think you mixesd between the tables "imagesInStories" to "Images" - where the primary key is.

Comment: i wasn't correcting the error. Just pasting the original query here to highlight the problem